# Aozora versus Aoi sora

Tags: words, adjectives, i-adjectives

Can we use 青空 and 青い空 interchangeably?

Is there any difference between the two? Which is the most natural?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this specific case, yes, 青空 and 青い空 both mean "blue sky". When used on their own, there is no surprising connotation and thus they are interchangeable. But 青空～ in a compound noun can mean "open-air" or "outdoor" (e.g., [青空教室](https://jisho.org/word/%E9%9D%92%E7%A9%BA%E6%95%99%E5%AE%A4) is not the same as 青い空教室).

Note that it's not always true for similar pairs. [白紙](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%99%BD%E7%B4%99) is not the same as 白い紙, and [赤本](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%B5%A4%E6%9C%AC) is not the same as 赤い本.

Comment: Thank you! So, hakushi means leaflet, which is not just paper that is white. And akahon is pulp fiction, not any red book. So, when we mean a color of some object, we can always use an i/na adjective + noun and never be mistaken. Am I right?

Comment: @Enguroo Yes. Ah, 黒板 is different from 黒い板 just as "blackboard" is different from "black board" :-)